# Using Reshape Cast

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to reshape an example dataframe by the following.

```
df<-data.frame(market = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),companyName =  c("foo","foo","foo", "bar","bar","bar"), val = seq(1,6))
require(reshape)
dfNew <- cast(df,market ~ companyName+companyName)
```

To generate:

```
      market        company 1   company 2    
1      a                1           4
2      b                2           5
3      c                3           6
```

But I get this error:

```
Using val as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reshape` and `reshape2` are both deprecated packages at this point. If you use Hadley's latest version, `tidyr`:

```
spread(df, key = companyName, value = val)

  market bar foo
1      a   4   1
2      b   5   2
3      c   6   3
```